# How to implement a database in Tkinter switching between frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, tkinter, frame

I'm working based on [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter), and it's still a project in process but I have a recurrent problem using databases.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import sqlite3

import threading

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.resizable(0,0)

        self.title("Findex")

        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()

        self.overrideredirect(1)

        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Inicio, Registro, RegistroError, Consulta):

            page_name = F.__name__

            frame=F(parent = container, controller = self)

            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame("Inicio")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):

        frame = self.frames[page_name]

        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):

        return self.frames[page_class]

class Inicio(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        labelInicio = tk.Label(self, text = "Bienvendido a Findex")

        labelInicio.pack()

        botonIncio = tk.Button(self, text = "Comenzar", 
            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Registro"))

        botonIncio.pack()

class Registro(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        def Usuario():

            if entryNombre.get() == "":

                labelError.config(text = "No introdujo ningún nombre")

            else:

                labelError.config(text = "")

                labelNombre = tk.Label(self,
                 text = "Ha escrito " + entryNombre.get() +
                  " ¿es correcto?")

                labelNombre.pack()

                def Paso():

                    controller.show_frame("Consulta")

                def Tiempo():

                    timer = threading.Timer(3.0, Paso)

                    timer.start()

                    labelAcceso = tk.Label(self,
                     text = "Adelante, " + entryNombre.get())

                    labelAcceso.pack()

                botonSi = tk.Button(self, text = "Sí",
                 command = Tiempo)

                botonSi.pack()

                botonNo = tk.Button(self, text = "No", 
                    command = lambda: controller.show_frame("RegistroError"))

                botonNo.pack()

        labelInstruction = tk.Label(self,
         text = "Para continuar introduzca su nombre")

        labelInstruction.pack()

        entryNombre = tk.Entry(self)

        entryNombre.pack()

        botonConfirmar = tk.Button(self, text = "Confirmar",
         command = Usuario)

        botonConfirmar.pack()

        labelError = tk.Label(self)

        labelError.pack()

class RegistroError(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        def Usuario():

            if entryNombre.get() == "":

                labelError.config(text = "No introdujo ningún nombre")

            else:

                labelError.config(text = "")

                labelNombre = tk.Label(self,
                 text = "Ha escrito " + entryNombre.get() +
                  " ¿es correcto?")

                labelNombre.pack()

                def Paso():

                    controller.show_frame("Consulta")

                def Tiempo():

                    timer = threading.Timer(2.0, Paso)

                    timer.start()

                    labelAcceso = tk.Label(self,
                     text = "Adelante, " + entryNombre.get())

                    labelAcceso.pack()

                botonSi = tk.Button(self, text = "Sí",
                 command = Tiempo)

                botonSi.pack()

                def Error():

                    labelNombre.config(text = "")

                    labelInstruction.config(text = "")

                    botonSi.config(state = "disabled")

                    botonNo.config(state = "disabled")

                    entryNombre.config(state = "disabled")

                    botonConfirmar.config(state = "disabled")

                    labelFin = tk.Label(self, 
                        text = "Se han agotado las oportunidades. Inténtelo de nuevo")

                    labelFin.pack()

                    def Salir():

                        quit()

                    botonSalir = tk.Button(self, text = "Aceptar y Salir", 
                        command = Salir)

                    botonSalir.pack()

                botonNo = tk.Button(self, text = "No" , command = Error)

                botonNo.pack()

        labelInstruction = tk.Label(self,
         text = "Para continuar introduzca su nombre")

        labelInstruction.pack()

        entryNombre = tk.Entry(self)

        entryNombre.pack()

        botonConfirmar = tk.Button(self, text = "Confirmar",
         command = Usuario)

        botonConfirmar.pack()

        labelError = tk.Label(self)

        labelError.pack()

class Consulta(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        labelConsulta = tk.Label(self, 
            text = "Ingrese el nombre de un producto, marca o tienda",
             padx = 30, pady = 15)

        labelConsulta.pack()

        entryConsulta = tk.Entry(self)

        entryConsulta.pack()

        def Call():

            miConexion = sqlite3.connect("Findex")

            miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

            query = entryConsulta.get()

            miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE = ? OR MARCA = ? OR ESTABLECIMIENTO = ?", query)

            table = miCursor.fetchall()

            textConsulta.insert(1.0, table)

            miConexion.commit()

        botonConsulta = tk.Button(self, text = "Buscar", command = Call)

        botonConsulta.pack()

        textConsulta = tk.Text(self, bd = 2)

        textConsulta.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = SampleApp()

    app.mainloop()
```

And here's where I create the database:

```
    import sqlite3

miConexion = sqlite3.connect("Findex")

miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

miCursor.execute("""

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'PRODUCTOS' (

    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),
    MARCA VARCHAR(50),
    PESO INTEGER,
    UNIDAD VARCHAR(20),
    PRECIO INTEGER,
    CATEGORIA VARCHAR(50),
    ESTABLECIMIENTO VARCHAR(50))

    """)

datos = [

    ("Sirope", "Suli", 700, "mililitros", 300, "Bebidas", "Palí"),
    ("Azúcar", "Doña María", 2, "kilogramos", 1225, "Granos",  "Palí"),
    ("Arroz", "Indiana", 1800, "gramos", 1495, "Granos", "Palí"),
    ("Café", "Rey", 500, "gramos", 1525, "Bebidas", "Palí"),
    ("Frijoles", "Indiana", 900, "gramos", 1175, "Granos", "Palí"),
    ("Sal", "Sal Sol", 500, "gramos", 225, "Granos", "Palí"),
    ("Aceite", "Clover", 1.5, "litros", 675, "Aceite/Margarina/Mantequilla", "Palí"),
    ("Huevos", "Don Cristóbal", 500, "gramos", 1975, "Huevos", "Palí"),
    ("Cereal", "Jack's", 250, "gramos", 2100, "Cereales", "Palí"),
    ("Mantequilla", "Dos Pinos", 500, "gramos", 675, "Aceite/Margarina/Mantequilla", "Palí"),
    ("Leche", "Dos Pinos", 1, "litros", 504, "Lácteos", "Palí"),
    ("Fideos", "Roma", 200, "gramos", 485, "Pastas", "Palí"),
    ("Jabón", "Fort 3", 1, "kilogramos", 550, "Limpieza", "Palí"),
    ("Desinfectante", "Floral", 750, "mililitros", 550, "Limpieza", "Palí"),
    ("Crema dental", "Oral B", 53, "mililitros", 900, "Cuidado personal", "Palí"),
    ("Jabón de baño", "Protex", 110, "gramos", 505, "Cuidado personal", "Palí"),
    ("Galletas", "Pozuelo", 31.5, "gramos", 1400, "Snacks", "Palí"),
    ("Papel higiénico", "Nevax", 1000, "hojas", 2450, "Cuidado personal", "Palí"),
    ("Toallas", "Nevax", 100, "hojas", 1300, "Limpieza", "Palí"),
    ("Refresco", "Lio-Té", 100, "gramos", 240, "Bebidas", "Palí"),
    ("Leche", "Delactomy", 1000, "mililitros", 2795, "Lácteos", "Perimercados"),
    ("Jamón cocido", "Cinta Azul", 250, "gramos", 2285, "Embutidos", "Perimercados"),
    ("Salsa inglesa", "Banquete", 700, "gramos", 1950, "Salsas", "Perimercados"),
    ("Aceite", "Capullo", 900, "mililitros", 925, "Aceite/Margarina/Mantequilla", "Perimercados"),
    ("Detergente", "Xedex", 5000, "gramos", 7750, "Limpieza", "Perimercados"),
    ("Lavaplatos", "Axion", 850, "gramos", 1610, "Limpieza", "Perimercados"),
    ("Arroz", "Imperio", 1, "kilogramos", 1180, "Granos", "Perimercados"),
    ("Pasta tipo cabello ángel", "Roma", 250, "gramos", 645, "Pastas", "Perimercados"),
    ("Pan blanco", "Bimbo", 450, "gramos", 1285, "Panes", "Perimercados"),
    ("Frijoles molidos", "Ducal", 400, "gramos", 910, "Enlatados", "Perimercados"),
    ("Crema dental", "Colgate", 75, "mililitros", 1390, "Cuidado personal", "Perimercados"),
    ("Protectores diarios", "Saba", 60, "unidades", 1495, "Cuidado personal", "Perimercados"),
    ("Café", "1820", 340, "gramos", 2810, "Bebidas", "Perimercados"),
    ("Avena", "Quaker", 300, "gramos", 805, "Cereales", "Perimercados"),
    ("Yogurt", "Yoplait", 750, "gramos", 1610, "Lácteos", "Perimercados"),
    ("Tomate", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 1050, "Frutas", "Perimercados"),
    ("Uvas mixtas", "-", 500, "gramos", 2600, "Frutas", "Perimercados"),
    ("Muslo de pollo", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 2300, "Carnes", "Perimercados"),
    ("Chorizo", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 3020, "Carnes", "Perimercados"),
    ("Queso", "Zarcero", 1, "kilogramos", 4200, "Lácteos", "Perimercados"),
    ("Aceite", "Capullo", 900, "mililitros", 880, "Aceite/Margarina/Mantequilla", "Megasuper"),
    ("Café", "Rey Selecto", 500, "gramos", 1995, "Bebidas", "Megasuper"),
    ("Margarina", "Numar", 452, "gramos", 1045, "Aceite/Margarina/Mantequilla", "Megasuper"),
    ("Yogurt", "Coronado", 1000, "mililitros", 1675, "Lácteos", "Megasuper"),
    ("Galleta soda", "Gama", 192, "gramos", 470, "Snacks", "Megasuper"),
    ("Molida premium de res", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 5540, "Carnes", "Megasuper"),
    ("Queso Turrialba", "Dos Pinos", 1, "kilogramos", 4270, "Lácteos", "Megasuper"),
    ("Chile dulce", "-", 1, "unidades", 325, "Verduras", "Megasuper"),
    ("Sandía", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 595, "Frutas", "Megasuper"),
    ("Huevos", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 1650, "Huevos", "Megasuper"),
    ("Hongos rebanados", "Del Monte", 184, "gramos", 530, "Enlatados", "Megasuper"),
    ("Frijoles rojos", "Luisiana", 900, "gramos", 1095, "Granos", "Megasuper"),
    ("Papel higiénico", "Higienol", 4, "unidades", 1550, "Limpieza", "Megasuper"),
    ("Detergente en polvo", "Rinso", 5000, "gramos", 1650, "Limpieza", "Megasuper"),
    ("Alimento para perro", "Dog Chow", 4000, "gramos", 10640, "Mascotas", "Megasuper"),
    ("Chuleta de cerdo", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 3690, "Carnes", "Megasuper"),
    ("Cerveza", "Imperial", 350, "mililitros", 780, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "Megasuper"),
    ("Vino", "Clos", 750, "mililitros", 3320, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "Megasuper"),
    ("Posta de cerdo", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 3490, "Carnes", "Megasuper"),
    ("Toallas sanitarias", "Kotex", 12, "unidades", 1645, "Ciudades personal", "Megasuper"),
    ("Crema dental", "Colgate", 75, "mililitros", 1510, "Cuidado personal", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Frito Lay", "Tostitos", 283, "gramos", 2620, "Snacks", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Vino", "San Telmo", 750, "mililitros", 7915, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Helado Trirts", "Dos Pinos", 540, "gramos", 2950, "Lácteos", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Repollo verde", "-", 1, "unidades", 695, "Verduras", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Néctar mixto fruta", "Dos Pinos", 1, "litros", 960, "Bebidas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Pan baguette", "AMMM", 300, "gramos", 1000, "Panadería", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Sandía", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 850, "Frutas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Tomate", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 1250, "Frutas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Plátono verde", "-", 1, "unidades", 395, "Frutas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Papa", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 1295, "Verduras", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Manga", "-", 1, "kilogramos", 1650, "Frutas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Ron", "Flor de Caña", 750, "mililiros", 7000, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Papas tostadas", "Lays", 184, "gramos", 1800, "Snacks", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Jugo de naranja", "Dos Pinos", 1.8, "litros", 2930, "Bebidas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Sundae", "Dos Pinos", 110, "gramos", 1620, "Lácteos", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Bebida energética", "Gatorade", 600, "mililitros", 1460, "Bebidas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Deligurt", "Dos Pinos", 200, "mililitros", 850, "Lácteos", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Gaseosa", "Coca Cola", 2, "litros", 2285, "Bebidas", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Papas tostadas", "Pringles", 125, "gramos", 2300, "Snacks", "Freshmarket"),
    ("Toalla nocturna", "Saba", 40, "unidades", 5575, "Cuidado personal", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Acondicionador para cabello", "Alea", 500, "mililitros", 4215, "Cuidado personal", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Shampoo con keratina", "Suave", 373, "mililitros", 4000, "Cuidado personal", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Atún en trozos", "Pronto", 640, "gramos", 7320, "Enlatados", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Café", "Rey", 400, "gramos", 3500, "Bebidas", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Frijoles molidos", "Ducal", 400, "gramos", 865, "Enlatados", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Mayonesa con aceite de oliva", "Alolivo", 400, "gramos", 1595, "Salsas", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Cereal integral", "Nestle", 450, "gramos", 2700, "Cereales", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Vino tinto", "Broquel", 750, "mililitros", 10785, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Queso mozzarella", "Crystal Farms", 227, "gramos", 3250, "Lácteos", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Jamón de pavo", "Cinta Azul", 1, "kilogramos", 9925, "Embutidos", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Bistec de lomo", "AutoMercado", 1, "kilogramos", 14170, "Carnes", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Chicharrones ahumados", "Jack's", 75, "gramos", 1400, "Carnes", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Maní con miel", "The Carolina Nut Co", 340, "gramos", 3100, "Snacks", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Limón ácido", "-", 15, "unidades", 3800, "Frutas", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Filet de pechuga", "AutoMercado", 1, "kilogramos", 7875, "Carnes", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Cerveza amarga", "Warsteiner", 500, "mililitros", 1395, "Bebidas alcohólicas", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Crema croporal", "Bilka", 180, "mililitros", 10265, "Cuidado Personal", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Tinte para cabello", "Koleston", 1, "unidades", 5915, "Cuidado Personal", "AutoMercado"),
    ("Toallitas desmaquillantes", "Asepxia", 25, "unidades", 5445, "Cuidado Personal", "AutoMercado")

    ]

miCursor.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", datos)

miConexion.commit()

miConexion.close()
```

I expect write the name, mark or shop of a product and insert all the information about the products that match with the entry in the text field, but it gives me 'OperationalError' or 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
query = entryConsulta.get()
miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE = ? OR MARCA = ? OR ESTABLECIMIENTO = ?", query)
```

your statment accept 3 args but you pass only one

try so

```
query = entryConsulta.get()
args = (query,query,query)
miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE = ? OR MARCA = ? OR ESTABLECIMIENTO = ?", args)
```

anyway I think that you have to decoupling your code between more modules, if you are interested on this type of program I would suggest you this my 
didactic work on github

https://github.com/1966bc/Tkinterlite

Hasta luego;)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. I know I have to separate my code in different modules, but I like make all together and then separate it. Also, thank you for the link, it looks very interesting and useful.